# Implements a generic method from two simple methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I'm trying to think of a generic method that will help me with the current code. It's not a problem, I just want to find out if it's possible to do it. I have two methods that basically do the same thing, but they use different transformations. I'm thinking about how to implement a generic method to make this code.

```
private void ImagePieceClickEvent(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
//imagePiceTarget has Transform type
        if (imagePieceTarget != null && imagePieceTarget != target.transform)
            imagePieceTarget.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(0.7f, 0.2f);
        if (imagePieceTarget == target.transform)
        {
            imagePieceTarget.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(0.7f, 0.2f);
            imagePieceTarget = null;
        }
        else
        {
            imagePieceTarget = target.transform;
            imagePieceTarget.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(1f, 0.2f).OnComplete(CheckAnswer);
        }
    }
}

private void ClonePieceClickEvent(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
//clonePieceTarget has Transform type
        if (clonePieceTarget != null && clonePieceTarget != target.transform)
            clonePieceTarget.transform.DOScale(0.7f, 0.2f);
        if (clonePieceTarget == target.transform)
        {
            clonePieceTarget.transform.DOScale(0.7f, 0.2f);
            clonePieceTarget = null;
        }
        else
        {
            clonePieceTarget = target.transform;
            clonePieceTarget.transform.DOScale(1f, 0.2f).OnComplete(CheckAnswer);
        }
    }
}
```

All the code in the IF condition, be implemented in a generic method then call it. Why can not I do this because the first method calls the .DOFade () method, while the second method calls the DOScale ().
I'd like to know if it's possible to simplify with a generic method, thanks.

Comment: Generic methods typically accept a parameter that can be of multiple types. A generic method seems not to be an option to simplify your code. You can read more about generic methods e.g. here: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/generic-methods-in-c/

Comment: that was the dilemma, I was thinking about simplifying, and I was thinking about a generic method....anyway thank you for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `System.Action` and the [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) to handle your problem.

Try the following:

```
private void PieceClickEvent(Transform target, MouseEventType type, ref Transform pieceTarget, System.Action<Transform> onFocus, System.Action<Transform> onBlur )
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
        if (pieceTarget != null && pieceTarget != target && onBlur != null)
        {
            onBlur( pieceTarget ) ;
        }

        if (imagePieceTarget == target.transform)
        {
            if( onBlur != null )
                onBlur( pieceTarget ) ;

            pieceTarget = null;
        }
        else
        {
            pieceTarget = target;
            if( onFocus != null )
                onFocus( pieceTarget ) ;
        }
    }
}

// ...

PieceClickEvent(
    target.transform,
    type,
    ref imagePieceTarget,
    t => t.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(1f, 0.2f).OnComplete(CheckAnswer),
    t => t.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(0.7f, 0.2f)
);

PieceClickEvent(
    target.transform,
    type,
    ref clonePieceTarget,
    t => t.DOScale(1f, 0.2f).OnComplete(CheckAnswer),
    t => t.DOScale(0.7f, 0.2f)
);
```